# TinyGSM not able to connect to a network after adding code to the Arduino Loop

Tags: arduino, mqtt, iot, arduino-uno, gsm

I got the TinyGSM MqttClient.ino example working. But if I added my own code to the void loop() I started to see some really bizarre / weird behavior with this library. Added some functionality which is working just fine with Ethernet Shield + PubSubClient library, but somehow this code interrupts the normal behavior of the TinyGSM library. If the example code is able to normally connect to the mobile network (this code is located in the setup part of the code) then if I add some things into the loop the code is no longer even able to connect to the network (nonetheless connect to the server or publish / subscribe messages). I am just amazed. This seems utterly illogical to me as the Loop part comes after the Setup, meaning that the Setup part of the code should still work. How can this be happening? Also I am getting a punch of: "[255298] ### Unhandled: " messages in the Serial Monitor. What do these mean and where do they come from? And this is weird that they "pop-up" at any given moment. Is there some kind of "threading" simulated in the background or do these messages come from the SIM7000 module? This is the first time in my coding experience that part of the code which otherwise works and code (which should not be reached yet) mess with each other. Could this be a low memory issue?

```
Here's the output from Arduino compiler: 
Sketch uses 27054 bytes (83%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1432 bytes (69%) of dynamic memory, leaving 616 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

Link to the code that does not work: [mqtt_not_working.ino](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12UudnhgomzWhyXh55xCL0P-_42e7xMff/view?usp=sharing)
Link to the (reduced) code that works: [mqtt_working.ino](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rptslpDLpQZjv7NkV-JmKTbnGxAtHbJZ/view?usp=sharing)

Here's the Serial output of the non-working code:

```
Turning the modem on...
Module turned on!
Wait...
Initializing modem...
[24290] ### Unhandled: 
Modem Info: SIM7000E R1529
Waiting for network... fail
[106752] ### Unhandled: 
[107764] ### Unhandled: 
Network disconnected
[108773] ### Unhandled: 
[109785] ### Unhandled: 
[110797] ### Unhandled: 
[112056] ### Unhandled: 
[113068] ### Unhandled:
etc.
```

Here's the working code output (the part that makes the code unfunctional is commented out):

```
Turning the modem on...
Module turned on!
Wait...
Initializing modem...
[22600] ### TinyGSM Version: 0.11.5
[22600] ### TinyGSM Compiled Module:  TinyGsmClientSIM7000
[22724] ### Modem: SIMCOM SIM7000E
Modem Info: SIM7000E R1529
Waiting for network... success
Network connected
Connecting to internet.emt.ee[24081] ### Daylight savings time state updated.
[24098] ### Network time and time zone updated.
[40399] ### Daylight savings time state updated.
[40414] ### Network time and time zone updated.
 success
GPRS connected
=== MQTT NOT CONNECTED ===
Connecting to pylons-staging.sirrent.by success
Message arrived [mqtt/PylonIn]: {lock:0,booking:0,alarm:0}
lock: 0 booking: 0
[75299] ### Unhandled: +CIPRG0
Message arrived [mqtt/PylonIn]: {lock:0,booking:1,alarm:0}
lock: 0 booking: 1
Message arrived [mqtt/PylonIn]: {lock:0,booking:1,alarm:0}
lock: 0 booking: 1
Message arrived [mqtt/PylonIn]: {lock:0,booking:0,alarm:0}
lock: 0 booking: 0
```

Comment: If you want to get help, copy and paste your code that is not working in your post. Your code that is working is not relevant. Don't post your code in your google drive where people need to download the code to see it.

Comment: `### Unhandled` means either there is some AT commands was not properly handled or you are sending the wrong commands or using the wrong function call. For example, `### Unhandled: +CIPRG0` is definitely wrong because as far as I know, there is no such command as `AT+CIPRG0` in the library nor in SIM7000 AT Command manual.

Answer (score 0):

**The code that is named mqtt_not_working.ino is working perfectly on Arduino Mega**. On Arduino Mega I am using **hardware serial (Serial1)**. Actually the TinyGSM code is already made this way that it will automatically choose Serial1 on Arduino Mega.
I also tried the same code on another Arduino UNO board and it is still not working - with this test I eliminated the possibility of a faulty UNO board. Also tried a baud rate of 19200 instead of 9600 for software serial communication between Arduino UNO and the SIM7000 module - still no luck and seeing bizarre behavior.

**Therefore my best guess is that this issue is related to Arduino UNO limited memory**.

Comment: By default, unless explicitly set by a user sketch, TinyGSM actually handle the TCP response in chunks at 64 bytes each time (see the [source code](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM/blob/master/src/TinyGsmTCP.tpp#L18-L20)), the library itself doesn't use a lot of memory, so even UNO with 2kB RAM works. BTW, what is the firmware version of your module?